# Is anyone having issues with terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws not expecting any attributes?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

For example we are getting these errors here. It doesn't quite make sense

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on lambda.tf line 21, in module "lambda_function":
  21:   function_name      = "function-name"

An argument named "function_name" is not expected here.

Error: Unsupported argument

  on lambda.tf line 22, in module "lambda_function":
  22:   description        = "description here"

An argument named "description" is not expected here.

Error: Unsupported argument

  on lambda.tf line 23, in module "lambda_function":
  23:   handler            = "handlervalue"
```

Comment: I am facing a similar situation with terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws. Unsupported argument error for every argument.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an [running GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/31615) with Terraform v1.2.7 and reading from modules.

Reverting back to [Terraform v1.2.6](https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.2.6/) solved the problem for me.